# Convert string to Date in R: month abbreviated "dd-mmm-YYYY"

Tags: r, date

I have a vector of strings which I need to convert to dates. This only works for some of the dates which are in the format of "dd-mmm-YYYY".

Example: this works: `strptime("21-Sep-2017", format = "%d-%b-%Y")`
This does not work and returns `NA`: `strptime("21-Dec-2017", format = "%d-%b-%Y")`

What am I doing wrong or not seeing?

Comment: Both work fine for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because your `locale` is probably one where `December` is not abbreviated as `Dec`. Without changing your session settings, you could simply do

```
lubridate::parse_date_time("21-Dec-2017", orders = "d-b-Y", locale = "us")

[1] "2017-12-21 UTC"
```